# Getting data from IEnumerable Model from foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Beginner assistance needed!!
I have a reason to pull a group of data out of multiple db based models.  This is successful and I can see the data in the model as it is pulled.  I can iterate through the `foreach` ( with no internal code) watching the data go through it, but I am still not sure how to get the data out of the model to act on it (needs to be posted in a specific way to another table).

Controller

```
public ActionResult BuildEmptyEventClassComp()

       {
           var alllist = (from o in _db.Events
                          join o2 in _db.Event_Classes on o.EventID equals o2.EventID
                          where o.EventID.Equals(o2.EventID)
                          join o3 in _db.Class_Definitions on o2.ClassID equals o3.Class_Definition_ID
                          where o2.ClassID.Equals(o3.Class_Definition_ID)
                          where o.CurrentEvent.Equals(true)

                          select new EventClassCompListVM { EventName = o.EventName, EventDate = o.Date_Start, ClassName = o3.Class_Name, ClassOrder = o2.ClassOrder, MaxComp = o2.MaxComp, ClassID = o2.ClassID, EventID = o.EventID }).AsEnumerable();


           foreach (var emptylist in alllist)
           {
              **emptylist.EventID = alllist.EventID;**  //EventID cannot be found to populate

           }

           return RedirectToAction("../EventClass/ListEventClasses");
       }
```

ViewModel  (tried multiple ways to change this... but again the data is in the model as I would expect.. just cannot get it out!)

```
using System.Web;

namespace eManager.Web2.Models
{
    public class EventClassCompListVM{
        public int ECCLkey { get; set; }
        public int CompeditorId { get; set; }
        public int Comp_EventID { get; set; }
        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
        public int EventID { get; set; }
        public int ClassID { get; set; }
        public string CompName { get; set; }
        public string EventName { get; set; }
        public string CompMetricName { get; set; }
        public double CompMetric { get; set; }
        public int MaxComp { get; set; }
        public string ClassName { get; set; }
        public int ClassOrder { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Get it out? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, `alllist` is of type `IEnumerable<EventClassCompListVM>` while `emptylist` in your `foreach` loop is of type `EventClassCompListVM` so there's no way that the assignment `emptylist.EventID = alllist.EventID;` can ever be valid.

What you actually try to do there most probably is: `var myEmptyListEventId = emptylist.EventID;`

Comment: Thank you. I understand your logic.  I think I was over thinking it.  Works perfectly now.    Much appreciated.!